# Sort an array of numbers in awk

Tags: awk, gawk

How can I sort an array of numbers in awk? Consider "sortNum.awk" :

```
{
    split($0,a," ")
    for (i in a) print a[i]
    print "####"
    asort(a)
    for (i in a) print a[i]
}
```

Running with `echo "4 3 2 1" | awk -f sortNum.awk` gives

```
1
4
3
2
####
4
1
2
3
```

I am using GNU Awk version 3.1.8.

Comment: If you want it to just work and don't care about `awk` specifically, this is Perl one-liner: `echo "4 3 2 1" | perl -e "print join ' ', sort split '\s', <>"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`for (i in a)` doesn't select the indexes in numeric order, you need to do that explicitly.

```
{
    n = split($0,a," ");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) print a[i];
    print "####"
    asort(a)
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) print a[i];
}
```